# Ambiguity between IID_IDropTarget and Virtualtrees::IID_IDropTarget

Tags: c++, com, c++builder, virtualtreeview

I'm currently going through a process of refactoring includes to reduce compile time, and I've come across the following compile error:

`[C++ Error] some_class.cpp(53): E2015 Ambiguity between 'IID_IDropTarget' and 'Virtualtrees::IID_IDropTarget'`

The line of code it points to is:

```
 if (iid == IID_IUnknown || iid == IID_IDropTarget)
```

If I use `Virtualtrees::IID_IDropTarget` it compiles fine, however I need to use COMs IDropTarget interface which I have implemented. I believe the problem might be that the Virtualtrees component has another implementation of the IDropTarget interface and they are conflicting.

Any ideas how I can specify that I **don't** want `Virtualtrees::IID_IDropTarget`? Or the namespace I use for COM's IID_IDropTarget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM's `IID_DropTarget` is declared like so:

```
EXTERN_C const IID IID_IDropTarget;
```

Since it's `extern "C"`, it's in the root namespace:

```
::IID_IDropTarget
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepend the name with "::" - specify it as `::IID_IDropTarget` - this will effectively tell C++ that you want the one from global namespace.